# insertion of list to a plotly dash dropdown resulting in empty dropdown

Tags: python, plotly, dropdown

I have been watching various tutorials where a drop-down menu is created using dash core components. I was able to recreate the one demonstrated in [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22L_bXTj2Dw). The only thing I changed from that working code was that I replaced the dictionary within the `options` argument to a list of species that I would like the user to be able to choose from. I am okay with the label being the same as the value in the case of all the species and so I don't believe that I need the dictionary as per [dash plotly dropdown documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/dropdown).

Is there a reason that I cannot insert a list in the `options` argument? Either in the form of a variable name or the actual list itself?

**Expected outcome:**
List inserted to working code creates a dropdown containing all elements of the list

**Actual outcome:**
The dropdown is created without error but is empty

Here is the code that is not producing drop-down values:

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id = 'first-dropdown',
        options = [species],                #where species = long list of strings
        value = 'Pacific Water Shrew'       #one of the strings contained in species
    )
])

if __name__ =='__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: Is `species` already a list? If it is, you are creating a list of a list by doing `[species]` Try just doing `options = species`

Comment: Ahh that is a good point, I did not realize that. I will give it a try. However I guess I should have mentioned in my question that I also tried actually inserting species in its real form : `options = ['Pacifiic Water Shrew','Whihtebark Pine',......]` and that produced the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment, if `species` is a list, `[species]` is a list of lists.  Just pass the list.  Also beware typos,  values in your list in your comment were not consistent with **value** argument.

```
from dash import html, dcc
import dash

# Build App
# app = JupyterDash(__name__)
app = dash.Dash()
species = ['Pacific Water Shrew','Whihtebark Pine']
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id="first-dropdown",
            options=species,  # where species = long list of strings
            value="Pacific Water Shrew",  # one of the strings contained in species
        ),
        html.Pre(dash.__version__)
    ]
)

app.run_server()
```

Comment: thank you for your response. Your code ( exactly the same but with `Dash` instead of `JupyterDash` and without the `mode` argument as it produced an error) produce a drop-down. Howerver, as before, that drop down is empty instead of producing options [species].

Comment: modified to use dash, it works.  also added a `Pre` to display dash version that is 2.3.0